# Replace form field on change and on load

Tags: jquery

My form has two fields, a text field and a dropdown of Countries. If the user selects United States from the dropdown, then I replace the text field with a dropdown of US States.

```
// Set Request Quote default Country to US
$('.ginput_address_country select option[value="US"]').attr("selected",true);

$(".ginput_address_country select").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    
    // Get original State form field
    var stateFieldID = $(this).closest('.ginput_complex').find('.ginput_address_state input, .ginput_address_state select').attr('id');
    
    if(selectedCountry == 'US') {

        $('#' + stateFieldID).replaceWith(
            '<select name="'+stateFieldID+'" id="'+stateFieldID+'" aria-required="false">' +
            '<option value="">Select State</option>' +
            '<option value="AL">Alabama</option>' +
                '<option value="AK">Alaska</option>' +
                '</select>');
        } else {
            $('#' + stateFieldID).replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" name="'+stateFieldID+'" id="'+stateFieldID+'" value="" aria-required="false">');
        }
    });
})
```

If I want to set the dropdown to United States by default, how can I trigger the change on page load and still maintain the change event?

Comment: `$(() => $(".ginput_address_country select").trigger("change"));` will do what you've asked, but it will give a nasty FOUC (you'll see the input until js is ready to run).  Better would be to make the change as you build the HTML, depending on how you build the HTML (server-side).

Comment: Thanks for "triggering" my memory. Just added ```$('.ginput_address_country select').val('US').trigger('change');``` after the change event.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `$('.ginput_address_country select').val('US').trigger('change');` after the change event.